# MIPS jump and BNE address calculation

Tags: mips, cpu-architecture, mips32

Suppose the program counter (PC) is set to 0x20000000.Is it possible to use the jump (j) MIPS assembly instruction to set the PC to the address 0x40000000? Is it possible to use the branch-on-equal (beq) MIPS assembly instruction to set the PC to this same address?

Answer (score 4):

I believe you could use `jr` to jump to a 32bit address

```asm
li $t0, 0x40000000
jr $t0
```

Similarly you could use a branch and combine it with the above to perform this jump.

The reason why `BNE` is not suited for this is that it only operates on 16-bit offsets due to how instructions are encoded.

`0001 01ss ssst tttt iiii iiii iiii iiii` represents a `BNE` instruction where `sssss` and `ttttt` are the compared registers and `iiii iiii iiii iiii` the 16-bit offset (twos-complement to allow backwards offset as well).
This means that the `0x20000000` offset cannot be expressed in the 16-bits provided by this encoding.

The jump instruction behaves a bit differently in the way it uses the current PC to calculate the destination address. This is done by concatenating the first 6 bits of the current PC (which would be `0010 00` in this case) together with the destination stored in the immediate part of the encoding (which would be 26-bits filled with `0`). Thus the resulting address can only be `0x20000000`.

Jump-Register (`JR`) on the other hand allows to jump to full 32-bit addresses since it uses a register for the destination address and is not bound by the aforementioned instruction limitations.

Comment: Thanks for posting the solution :) Maybe you could elaborate more on why the jump instruction must be used instead of the branch jump instruction?

Comment: Sure thing, I just had to look up some specifications about instruction formats first. I hope this is now sufficient.

Comment: Awesome edit Minn! The answer itself is usually enough, but some clarification is nice to have for further reference and new readers with little knowledge about MIPS. I learned some things while reading your explanation. Keep up the good work!

Answer (score 1):

The documentation states the following in the *programming notes* section of the `BEQ`-instruction:

> **Description**: if rs = rt then branch An 18-bit signed offset (the
>   16-bit offset field shifted left 2 bits) is added to the address of
>   the instruction following the branch (not the branch itself), in the
>   branch delay slot, to form a PC-relative effective target address.
>
> **Programming Notes:** 
>   With the 18-bit signed instruction offset, the
>   conditional branch range is ± 128 Kbytes. Use jump (J) or jump
>   register (JR) instructions to branch to addresses outside this range.

So you cannot use the `BEQ` instruction to jump to `0x40000000` (starting from `0x20000000` it would have to jump over `0x20000000` = `536870912`b = `536871`kb). Thus you must use the jump register instructions to jump to `0x40000000`.